# Meteor constantly crashing: Error: write after end

Tags: meteor

My meteor instance is crashing after every refresh I do. Interestingly it does not happen when I run it inside a docker container.

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:430:15)
    at IncomingMessage.ondata (_stream_readable.js:542:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:368:10)
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:759:26)
    at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:739:3)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:458:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:372:17)
```

Any idea how I could further debug this issue?